# Find CMYK counts in bitmap pixels

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, bitmap, cmyk

1. RGB bitmap to CMYK?
2. Count the CMYK to read the colour depth?

or

1. Count RGB values(done), not convert RGB --> CMYK using ICC profile

How to find the percentage of CMYK in bitmap. Similar to Ghostscript API. I can't use this in my program because it is not managed and doesn't support for parallel processing. I have done this using RGB [(as per this)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18757027/1834352) 
, but for printer friendliness need this in CMYK.

```
    public static bool IsCMYK(System.Drawing.Image image)
    {
        var flags = (ImageFlags)image.Flags;
        if (flags.HasFlag(ImageFlags.ColorSpaceCmyk) || flags.HasFlag(ImageFlags.ColorSpaceYcck))
        {
            return true;
        }

        const int PixelFormat32bppCMYK = (15 | (32 << 8));
        return (int)image.PixelFormat == PixelFormat32bppCMYK;
    } 

    public void ImagemagicTool(Bitmap bi)
    {
        ImageMagick.MagickImage img = new MagickImage(bi);
        string str= img.ColorSpace.ToString();
    }
    public ImageColorFormat GetColorFormat(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        const int pixelFormatIndexed = 0x00010000;
        const int pixelFormat32bppCMYK = 0x200F;
        const int pixelFormat16bppGrayScale = (4 | (16 << 8));

        // Check image flags
        var flags = (ImageFlags)bitmap.Flags;
        if (flags.HasFlag(ImageFlags.ColorSpaceCmyk) || flags.HasFlag(ImageFlags.ColorSpaceYcck))
        {
            return ImageColorFormat.Cmyk;
        }
        else if (flags.HasFlag(ImageFlags.ColorSpaceGray))
        {
            return ImageColorFormat.Grayscale;
        }

        // Check pixel format
        var pixelFormat = (int)bitmap.PixelFormat;
        if (pixelFormat == pixelFormat32bppCMYK)
        {
            return ImageColorFormat.Cmyk;
        }
        else if ((pixelFormat & pixelFormatIndexed) != 0)
        {
            return ImageColorFormat.Indexed;
        }
        else if (pixelFormat == pixelFormat16bppGrayScale)
        {
            return ImageColorFormat.Grayscale;
        }

        // Default to RGB
        return ImageColorFormat.Rgb;
    }
```

*Update:
Looks I have to separate the layers CMYK and then find the percentage of the each C,M,Y & K.How do I do that in bitmap stream? This might be complex, for simpler approach Finding RGB and then Convert RGB to CMYK based on ICC US webcotedSWOP v2 .ICC...

Just trying with the above mentioned, appreciate to put me in right direction

---

Now I have got the CMYK propotionate values for RGB in bitmap, but not sure about the desired result in percentage, is there any upper limit for CMYK?

```
public static CMYK RGBtoCMYK(int red, int green, int blue)
    {
        double c = (double)(255 - red) / 255;
        double m = (double)(255 - green) / 255;
        double y = (double)(255 - blue) / 255;

        double min = (double)Math.Min(c, Math.Min(m, y));
        if (min == 1.0)
        {
            return new CMYK(0, 0, 0, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            return new CMYK((c - min) / (1 - min), (m - min) / (1 - min), (y - min) / (1 - min), min);
        }
    }

  public class CMYK
{
    public double Cyan { get; set; }
    public double Magenta { get; set; }
    public double Yellow { get; set; }
    public double Black { get; set; }
    public CMYK()
    {
    }
    public CMYK(double cyan, double magenta, double yellow,double black)
    {
        Cyan = cyan;
        Magenta = magenta;
        Yellow = yellow;
        Black = black;
    }
}
public static void GetRGBlock(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        System.Drawing.Rectangle rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
        List<System.Drawing.Color> cols = new List<System.Drawing.Color>();
        int bytes = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmp.Height;
        byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int dx = 0;
        int l = 0;
        for (y = 0; y <= rect.Height - 1; y++)
        {
            l = y * bmpData.Stride;
            //calulate line based on stride
            for (x = 0; x <= rect.Width - 1; x++)
            {
                dx = l + x * 3;
                //3 for RGB, 4 for ARGB, notice l is used as offset
                cols.Add(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(rgbValues[dx + 2], rgbValues[dx + 1], rgbValues[dx]));
            }
        }          

        List<CMYK> cmykcols = new List<CMYK>();
        foreach (var item in cols)
            cmykcols.Add(RGBtoCMYK(item.R, item.G, item.B));

        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
        bmp.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The scanner likely uses a RGB colour model to store the images. If you want to recover something close to the true colour separations, then you will need to scan the image at a resolution much higher than the original screen and then locate the individual coloured dots.

In general, this will not be possible as the CMYK colours can be printed with overlaps intentionally and the many non-linear colour space effects in printing due to ink, paper, reader perception will make this complex.

Your best approach is likely to be to recover the RGB bitmap, and then create new separations again when printing. The problem is that you could see [Moiré](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%25C3%25A9_pattern) artifacts in the resulting images.

Comment: Thnks,what do you mean by new separation when printing.Nothing to worry on the scanning job,FYI this is for only existing PDF documents to check the ink coverage just like in the PDF Pro, when you check the output Preview gives you the ink coverage details in percentage for each page. I did it by RGB bitmap and getting the RGB percentage but I need accurate solution that matches the adobe CMYK values.Like RGB in pixels is possible to detect CMYK? or do I need to convert RGB to CMYK with any formulas?

Comment: If you don't intend to print the document again, then the problem is simpler. You will then still need to do the colour conversions. The colour gamut of the RGB colour space does not map uniquely to the CMYK so your results may not be completely correct. You should be able to evaluate some kind of canonical colour range to give you the coverage. You will need to carry out the conversions if it is essential to do the calculation in CMYK. You could try to get the coverage in RBG, at least first.

Comment: I have done that,I have RGB coverage details now but which one is best is the RGB values to CMYK conversion or RGB bitmap to CMYK bitmap?

Comment: I'm not sure how these are different. If you are talking about using different APIs for the two approaches, then you would have to look at their individual algorithms to decide which retains the original intent better. You also need to consider the non-uniqueness in CMYK when comparing the values. Remember also that most colour separations will selectively overlap pixels to allow ink to show through. Is there are reason that you can't compare the RGB values? these won't be the same, but with adequate resolution should give representative counts.