# Get most dominant color of a binary image. Is it black or white?

Tags: c#, colors, pixel

I have a bitmap image, and it is binarized. I want to get the most dominant color of the bitmap image, if it is black or white. I tried the `bitmap.getPixel(x,y)` method. I just wanna ask if there is other way?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no better way for that. You just need calculate black and white pixels count and get their percentage via total pixels count.

See [this theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757027/colour-percentage-in-bitmap) as example

Answer (score 0):

You can access raw bitmat data (copy it to `byte[]`) and then scan the array for 0 and 255 to count black and white pixels. Check [Bitmap.LockBits sample on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it almost what you are looking for.